# Wordpress feed error on syndication: "...URI is missing at line 1, column 48"

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss, syndication

Using multiple RSS Feed aggregators on WordPress, the are throwing an error on my feed:

> "This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML
>   error: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing at line 1, column 48"

[Feed URL](http://my.notjusttravel.com/holiday-offers/feed/)

I was using **FeedWordPress** plugin to syndicate between wordpress websites and then all of a sudden it started throwing this error. It appears to be a problem with the actual feed as different plugins throw the same error.

Note: the feed passes [W3 Validation](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.notjusttravel.com%2Fholiday-offers%2Ffeed%2F).

Can anyone spot what is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was getting this error was because my original Feed was on the same domain as the website I was syndicating to:

Original Feed: http://website.com/offers/feed/
Website to syndicate to:  http://website.com/site1/

By moving the original feed to a different sub domain such as http://offers.website.com/feed/ fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when the feed is showing invalid characters that haven't been escaped properly. The most common issue is with characters <,> and &

If it's passing the W3 validation then it's more likely to be the reader which is at fault

Comment: Yes I can see that, but the error is specifically pointing to "URI is missing at line 1, column 48" rather than a parser error / invalid characters.